# Android- Getting a single value from a database table using cursor

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm using cursors to retrieve data from a database. I know how to retrieve entire columns to use on listviews and such, but I'm struggling to find a way to retrieve a single value.

Let's say I have a table with two columns ("_id" and "Name") and I have ten records (rows) in that table. How would I get, for example, the Name in the third row? Considering I defined a cursor that reads that table:

```
public Cursor getMyNameInfo() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();


    String sqlTables = "MyNames";
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, null, null, null,
            null, null, null);  

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `c.moveToFirst()` use `c.moveToPosition(2)` (`Cursor` indexes are zero-based hence '2' is the third record).

Remember to check that the `Cursor` has valid data first though.

**EDIT:**

Once you've moved the cursor to the 3rd record as I explain above, use the following to just get the value of the "Name" column.

```
String theName = c.getString(getColumnIndex("Name"));
```

Comment: And that will return that single row?

Comment: A `Cursor` only ever points at a single row at any given time hence the use of the `moveTo...` methods.

Comment: @tyb: Also, see my edit for accessing on a single column value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getdata();

        System.out.println("colo" + cursor.getColumnCount() + ""
                + cursor.getCount());

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor != null) {

            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

                String chktitle = title.trim().toString();
                String str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));

                System.out.println("title :: "
                        + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
                System.out.println("date :: "
                        + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
                System.out.println("desc :: "
                        + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("desc")));

                if (chktitle.equals(str) == true) {
                    tvAddfavorite.setText("Remove Favorite");
                    break;
                }
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `WHERE` clause:

```
qb.appendWhere("_id = 2");
```

Comment: @tyb Before you make the query on the `SQLiteQueryBuilder qb`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers above I created the following method to give the value of an item from another column but in the same row.

```
public String getValueFromColumn(int position, String tableName, String columnToGetValueFrom) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    qb.setTables(tableName);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, null, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    c.moveToPosition(position);
    String neededValue = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columnToGetValueFrom));
    return neededValue;
}
```

Hope it helps anyone.